# GWT plugin fails to load in Eclipse 2022-03 with JDK 11 or 17 because of OSGI BundleException

Tags: eclipse, gwt, osgi

1. Downloaded Eclipse: `eclipse-java-2022-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
2. Installed GWT from this update site: `http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release/`
3. Tried various Java version (OpenJDK 11 and 17 from the repositories and downloaded from adoptium.net)
4. Always got the same problem:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.core [600]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform; bundle-version="3.0.0.201710131939"; singleton:="true"
       com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform [602]
         No resolution report for the bundle.  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses constraint violation.
  org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.0.0.201710131939"; osgi.identity="com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.servlet' from resources javax.servlet [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.0.0.v201112011016"; osgi.identity="javax.servlet"] and jakarta.servlet-api [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.0"; osgi.identity="jakarta.servlet-api"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.0.0.201710131939"; osgi.identity="com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (osgi.wiring.bundle=javax.servlet)
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: javax.servlet
  javax.servlet [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.0.0.v201112011016"; osgi.identity="javax.servlet"]

Chain 2:
  com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.0.0.201710131939"; osgi.identity="com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet)
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="10.0.6"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet"
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="10.0.6"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(&(version>=4.0.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.servlet
  jakarta.servlet-api [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.0"; osgi.identity="jakarta.servlet-api"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

My system as Eclipse describes it:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.23.0.I20220308-0310
java.version=17.0.3
java.vendor=Private Build
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data XXXXXXXXX
```

`uname -a`: `Linux mycomputername #25~20.04.2tux1 SMP Tue Apr 12 10:34:50 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Linux: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with "Budgie" desktop

I also tried another Eclipse version, but with the same results. (`eclipse-SDK-4.23-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`)

I found other `BundleException` problems, but [only one for GWT](https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/w2mCob7nB8g/m/223xLKxGAQAJ), and it had no answer. And the other problems are not applicable to this problem. They were caused by the application creator, but I am not the creator of GWT and others use it without problems.

### EDIT 2022.05.01:

I found no solution, but weird workarounds: If I use an Eclipse download without the "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" and use a ".p2f" file with an old Eclipse Update Site to install an old version of the "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" from there, then GWT works.

The problem is related to the `javax.servlet` ".jar" file. If Eclipse decided to download `javax.servlet_3.1.0.v201410161800.jar` GWT works. But if Eclipse decides to use `javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar` instead, GWT does not work. The weird thing is: Newer version of Eclipse use the older version of that ".jar", older version of Eclipse use the newer version of that ".jar".

With an Eclipse from `https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.23-202203080310/`, the following ".p2f" file results in a working GWT installation for me:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?p2f version='1.0.0'?>
<p2f version='1.0.0'>
  <ius size='3'>
    <iu id='org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group' name='Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools' version='3.22.0.v202103200058'>
      <repositories size='1'>
        <repository location='https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-06'/>
      </repositories>
    </iu>
    <iu id='com.gwtplugins.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt28.feature.feature.group' name='GWT 2.8.1 SDK' version='2.8.0.201710131939'>
      <repositories size='1'>
        <repository location='http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release'/>
      </repositories>
    </iu>
    <iu id='com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature.feature.group' name='GWT Eclipse Plugin' version='3.0.0.201710131939'>
      <repositories size='1'>
        <repository location='http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release'/>
      </repositories>
    </iu>
  </ius>
</p2f>
```

After that, uninstall the old "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" and install the current version from the current update site. GWT will remain working.

As I said, it's not a solution, just a weird workaround.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I build the plugin from source (against the dependencies of the latest Eclipse version), I get the following error when trying to install from the local update site:

No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,3.1.0.v201410161800

Comment: Manually adding a repository to the update sites that contains that bundle (for example  http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/3.7.0/site ) allowed me to successfully continue the installation.

Comment: I had this same problem until the new Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0) was released. 2023-03 (4.27.0) works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in the `com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform` bundle which uses Require-Bundle to access the `javax.servlet` package when it should have used Import-Package.

`com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform` Require-Bundle's the `javax.servlet` bundle and the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet` bundle which use different versions of the `javax.servlet` package and so the class loader cannot be properly constructed.

Comment: So what's the solution? What's the way to make it work?

Comment: You would need to repackage the com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform bundle to fix the manifest.

Comment: Okay, is there a write-up or how-to of the procedure?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to hand edit the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in the jar. But you must be careful to use the correct syntax and reference all the necessary javax.servlet packages in the Import-Package statement.

Comment: I'm not an eclipse developer so these are not directions that can be useful for me

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get GWT plugin that I discovered without changing eclipse install files by hand (let's admit, vast majority of developers are not going to be doing that) is this:

1. Download Eclipse 2021-09 Release from here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/r
2. Install GWT plugin from the marketplace
3. Update Eclipse to the latest version

Any Eclipse release after 2021-09 will not let you have GWT plugin successfully installed. Let's hope 2022-06 fixes that

Comment: 2022-06 did not fix the "can't install" issue. But installing 2021-09 and then upgrading it gives me version 2022-06 with working gwt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patched version: https://static.sapsailing.com/com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform_3.0.0.201710131939.jar
I've replaced the Require-Bundle by according Import-Package entries for the following packages:

- javax.servlet
- javax.servlet.http
- javax.servlet.annotation
- javax.servlet.descriptor
  With this bundle installed, and starting Eclipse with the "-clean" option I succeeded in getting the GWT menu item and launch configs back.

Comment: Does your -jar file directly integrate into Eclipse? I cannot get it to integrate ...

Comment: Yes, I replaced the equal-named jar in my Eclipse installation's plugins/ folder. Are you seeing any error message?

Comment: I installed both jee21-09 and jee22-09 on windows 11. I also successfully installed GWT 3.0 plugin. Just by Help-Install new Software - and using the link from the Github Working Group for the Plugin. Further I used the link on this page http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release as repository which installs me the plugin correctly. Note, the GWT plugin 3.0 is currently not available in the eclipse marketplace. In both installation I only find the following file in the plugin:directory:org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.300.v20210813-1054.jar ... any idea pls.?